# What is the length of the cosyzygy funtor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let A be a symmetric Nakayama algbebra and M and N uniserial A-modules with $l(M)\geq l(N)$. I want to prove that then $l(\Omega^{-1}(M))\leq l(\Omega^{-1}(N))$ with $\Omega^{-1}$ the cosyzygy functor.

In Auslander's "Representation theory of Artin algebras" this is used in the proof of Theorem 3.8 in Chapter X (p.358).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2074852/532409

Comment: This is not true, and neither do Auslander, Reiten and Smalø (the book you’re referring to has three authors) claim that it is.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Could you explain to me why it is true for the modules in the proof of Theorem 3.8 (a) and (b)?

Comment: I don't have time to read back through the text to check all the assumptions, but I'm guessing that it comes down to the fact that if $N$ and $M$ are uniserial modules with $N$ a submodule of $M$ (so $l(M)\geq l(N)$), then $M$ and $N $ have the same injective envelope $I$, and so $l(\Omega^{-1}(M))=l(I)-l(M)\leq l(I)-l(N)=l(\Omega^{-1}(N))$.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, all indecomposable injective A-modules are the same length. The injective envelope of a module is the same as the injective envelope of its socle. The socle of a uniserial module is simple. The injective envelope of a simple module is indecomposable. So the injective envelope of a uniserial module is also indecomposable. Altogether, this gives us:
$$l(\Omega^{-1}M)=l(I(M)/i_M(M))=l(I(M))-l(i_M(M))\\
=l(I(M))-l(M)\leq l(I(N))-l(N)=l(\Omega^{-1}N)$$